How can I solve error in this assembly code?
in solidity version ^0.8.x I have this error:
ParserError: Call or assignment expected.
  --> voting1.sol:53:17:
   |
53 |             loop:
   |                 ^

my code is:
assembly {
            loop:
                jumpi(end, iszero(bit))
                r := mulmod(mulmod(r, r, m), exp(b, iszero(iszero(and(e, bit)))), m)
                r := mulmod(mulmod(r, r, m), exp(b, iszero(iszero(and(e, div(bit, 2))))), m)
                r := mulmod(mulmod(r, r, m), exp(b, iszero(iszero(and(e, div(bit, 4))))), m)
                r := mulmod(mulmod(r, r, m), exp(b, iszero(iszero(and(e, div(bit, 8))))), m)
                bit := div(bit, 16)
                jump(loop)
            end:
        }

how can I solve the error?

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.6/assembly.html#labels
